Branching strategy for releasing only approved/tested code
Goal
I have a similar goal/question to this one (that's over 6yrs old now), and I'm just checking to see if there has been any changes in the Git/Azure DevOps world that can assist me.
Background
Our current strategy is that we have:

dev branch where all developers use during the course of a sprint

all development done on short-lived "feature" branches + peer-reviewed by pull requests (PR) into dev when development for a given work item is done
CI/CD process on updates to dev automatically build & deploy to DEV environment for initial testing to be done.


main branch which (should) contain all "approve/tested" changes

When all code in dev is in a releasable state, a PR/merge is done into main from dev.
Similar CI/CD process on updates to main automatically create a build ready for auto/manual deployment to TEST, UAT, PROD environments (depending on build passing each stage).



Problem
The main issue we're experiencing with this process is when there's a new change that is blocking the next release (either a change fails testing, or a new UAT release needs to be cut before all new changes have been fully tested), and we are unable to proceed until ALL issues have been resolved (or we risk introducing known faults/unapproved changes).
Things we've considered
Most recently, I suggested a redesign of the dev process such that no code could be integrated (e.g. PR'd into dev) until it had passed ALL tests/approval.
Unfortunately, the rest of the dev team highlighted that, while this seems good - in practice this means that all changes are tested isolation, which can end up breaking later when finally integrated/PR'd to codebase, rather than finding out sooner.
Does anyone have any alternative suggestions for a solution (that scales well)?
Many thanks in advance
(+please let me know if any of the above needs clarifying)

An alternative is to merge (only validated) feature branches into a release/something branch (branched off main) which can trigger some build on a test environment, then be merged into main when you're ready for production. Reminds me of a recent similar question I answered.

Thx for the suggestion, @RomainValeri.
Alas, per my "Things we've considered" section - this was something I recently posed to the dev team. Alas, several of them highlights other issues with this (one with recent "bad" experience). I'm suspecting there isn't likely to be a silver bullet here, but just wanted to ensure I'd not missed a recently Git/Azure DevOps feature. Thx again

See Git patterns and anti-patterns for successful developers : Build 2018.
Related blog post: Release Flow: How We Do Branching on the VSTS Team.

I just added the branching-strategy tag to this question. A strict interpretation of opinion based questions might rule out all questions asking for advice in choosing a branching strategy. The fact that the tag exists though, implies that perhaps this type of question should be allowed. Regardless, this question certainly has value to others, as this is a common problem that can be solved by tweaking a workflow in various ways. Which way is best could be considered an opinion, but so are many questions on this site with multiple highly ranked answers.

Thanks @TTT, much appreciated. I was surprised to see it get closed (and have voted to it to be reopened) - as while I can see there's no simple Q/A for this - I asked for an answer, and have had some great responses (with potentially more than one to proceed with) - so I've found the answers to be very helpful+informative already, and agree, they would hopefully be useful to others.

Continuous Delivery isn't compatible with sprint-based deployments. You may consider Theory of Constraints or Just-in-Time (what IT mistakenly calls Kanban). Or if you use sprint-based approaches like Scrum, at least do it for everything else but releases.
The approach that works for me is this:

Devs must not produce low-quality work. They need to write automated tests and check things manually before they integrate into the trunk.
Use Pull-systems like Just-in-time or Theory of Constraints. Meaning - Test team grants the permission to the dev team to push new changes to the trunk. This way only small number of tasks will be tested at the same time - the rest are waiting in line even if they finished. For this to work well you need:

Enough resourced on the Test side. If your Test team is overloaded, the Dev team will be blocked too often.
Dev team should be allowed to push changes that don't require testing. Documentation and tests are certainly good candidates. But if features are done in small increments, then it's often possible for the developer to be sure there are no defects. But you should be ready that sometimes bugs will slip through. Admittedly, this one is quite painful - everyone usually has a lot of question of what's considered "safe enough" to be pushed bypassing Test team.
Feature flags, branching by abstraction, functionality-that-is-not exposed - it should be possible for Devs to organize their changes so that they don't have any impact on the user, even if they are deployed to prod.


You don't need dev branch. As soon as the change is ready (written, tested, reviewed if needed) - it goes directly to the trunk (once Test team is ready).

Still, the most important here is the item #1. If you have high quality, then it's safer to ship to prod even if it's not tested or testers missed something.


"Continuous Delivery isn't compatible with sprint-based deployments."
Thank you @stanislav-bashkyrtsev for confirming something I've been battling with (but had missed) for a while now. Yes, I should've said - we are using Scrum, with 2 week sprints.  Alas, it's more the release frequency (typically timed toward end of sprints) that's driving the release process (customer's choice/insistence). Thx again for the details - lots to think on.


There ways to isolate yourself from customer choice/insistence. After every build you have a binary version of the product, right? So it's possible to jot down which version was "virtually released". And then at the end of the sprint you could take the latest "virtual release version" and put deploy it to PRD. This way you can have both - the Pull system and the sprint-based deployments.

I believe your problem stems from:

(PR) into dev when development for a given work item is done.

Followed by:

automatically build & deploy to DEV environment for initial testing to be done.

Basically this means that dev isn't necessarily ready for production yet. It might be, and perhaps usually is by the end of the sprint, but if even 1 thing on dev isn't ready when you wish to release to production:

we are unable to proceed until ALL issues have been resolved

The solutions to this (common) problem can be divided into 2 general categories. #1 is to assume dev is usually correct, and make it easier to fix it when it isn't. #2 is to assume dev is currently rarely ready to go at any specific time, and to change that by performing more testing before merging into dev.
Solution Type #1: Revert Problems on dev:
If the problem doesn't happen very often, then this is the simplest thing to do because you don't really need to modify your workflow (much). The idea here is you try to fix something before the deadline and if you can't, you just revert the change out of dev. If you wish to go this route, when completing PRs in Azure DevOps, consider not using the "rebase and fast-forward option". Instead use one of the other 3 choices: regular "Merge", "Squash", or "Semi-linear merge" (aka Rebase merge). The reason is with the latter 3, any PR can be undone by reverting a single commit (either the merge commit or the squash commit). With rebase and fast-forward you have an unknown number of commits you would need to revert. (Side Note: when it comes time to merge dev into main, you should only use a regular "Merge".)
Solution Type #2: Test more before merging into dev:
(Note this is similar to your proposal, but this is still integration testing, because everyone shares it.)
If it happens fairly regularly, or if you find lots of bug fixes happening on dev throughout the sprint, adding (or replacing dev with) another pre-test branch may be useful. This is called Gitworkflow and is what the Git repository uses. The basic premise is that you have a branch called next, which is where code merges into first. The feature can be tweaked by merging updates into next multiple times until it's fully tested. Once ready, the branch can be cleaned up and merged into dev. (Or if you had CI/CD it could be immediately merged into main and you could get rid of dev.) Note that with this strategy, next gets messy over time, so you need to periodically reset it to dev; I suggest at least once per iteration.

Here's a related answer which uses a hybrid strategy of Gitworkflow with Git Flow.
